# jQuery UI detect if some dragging on a page is under processing by the moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I need to detect if there is some dragging on a page processing by the moment of checking. It should not be determined inside of any event (incidentally). The dragging event itself may be occurred by jQueryUI(Draggable), or with a native `onDrag(...)` event.

I need something like:

```
function isSomethingBeingDragged(){
    return ['drag', 'dragstart', 'dragend', 'drop'].some(v => ~eventsListByTheMoment.indexOf(v));
}
```

But I do not know how to implement `eventsListByTheMoment` without using some external listeners to catch those events and to serve data in some variables.

Comment: Each of the jQuery UI Events (other than draggable) use unique naming conventions so they do not conflict with native events.

Comment: Ok, thx, i've already dealed with it, that's my mistake. Turning back over the main question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.